# Calculating business days to a date PHP

Tags: php, date, logic

Im coding an a system like a product withdraw system, for example: Certain product category has X days to be withdrawn.

Category | Buziness Days
1 | 1
2 | 3
3 | 4
4 | 3
5 | 3
6 | 3
7 | 4

For example, today is 2019-05-22 wednesday: IF my product was category 7, + 4 days, my withdraw will be in 2019-05-28.

And I have another "problem", that system was build in PHP 4!

Thanks!

Comment: Great! So what have you [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)?

Comment: I have done my JOB using DateTime and using modify('+5 weekdays')

But this function just work on php 5 :(

Comment: Well I hate to say it, but the first problem I would be solving is the fact that you are running PHP 4. Heck, PHP 5.5 has dropped support in 2016, and PHP 7.0 is already considered [*'end of life'*](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php). PHP 4 [*hasn't been supported since 2008*](https://www.php.net/eol.php), and you're exposing yourself to a raft of security vulnerabilities by not updating.

Comment: Yeh I knew it, but it is not my project... his owner does not want to update that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Date and strtotime has used and its been from [PHP4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
<?php
$CurrentDate = date('Y-m-d');
$businessdays = 4;
$checkloop = 0;
While($checkloop<$businessdays){
    $CurrentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( "$CurrentDate + 1 day" ));
    $day = date('l', strtotime($CurrentDate));
    if($day!='Saturday' && $day!='Sunday')
        ++$checkloop;
}
print_r($CurrentDate);
print_r($day);
?>
```

Output

Current Date is 2019-05-21

2019-05-27 Monday